# How to use another CSS Style while the main div is on hide

Tags: css

i'm having trouble giving a div a specific style. Let me explain a little bit better: I am using 2 divs for a webapp, the first one is a popup notification like the IOS one, and the other one is just an image to join the page where are few product updates (So every-time I update a product, it shows a popup notification near the corner of the image).

The problem I'm having is that i had to use `padding-top: -28px` to align the popup div `#popupContact` and the image div `.imatges3` with the other images. When you click on the popup div (or in the image as well), it disappears, and the image div moves a bit upper, indeed stay at the same spot (because the div disappeared and keep applying the padding-top).

Is any way to give a different CSS value to a div, depending on if it has another div hiding or not? (Give another value depending on if the main div disappeared or not)

Thanks.

**Example:**

```
<div class="imatges3" id="pop"><div id="popupContact"><span class="boton">3</span></div>        
    <a href="actualizacion.html">  
       <img src="actprod.png" alt="Product Updates" border="0">
    </a>    
</div>
```

**and css**

```
.imatges3 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-top: -28px;
}

#popupContact{
   display:none;
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   z-index:200;
   font-size:13px;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 8px;
   color: #ffffff;
   padding: 0px 0px;

   position: relative;
   top:30px;
   left:75px;   
}
```

Comment: And the HTML for the div you're hiding/showing? If you're *only* hiding/showing a div then CSS is unlikely to help supply alternate styles based on visibility. If you use a class-name to hide/show then it's possible using an adjacent-sibling combinator to offer different styles.

Comment: I added the div i'm trying to switch showing. The hided one is the PopupContact div, but the Padding added to "imatges3" modifys the display of the div when the PopupContact is hiding, so I want to know how to modify the css only when this one is hiding (for align the imatges3 div with the other ones).

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try With  following css for both divs

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: I just need to apply another style while the other div is hidding. Maybe Jquery?